Python 3.12.2 can't install Selenium 4.19 distribution package
I've installed Python (version 3.12.2) in my offline environment.  I'm looking to install the latest version of Selenium (version 4.19) via distribution from the Selenium website and imported into my offline environment.  Upon running "pip install..." to install Selenium I receive the error as highlighted below in the screen capture.  I can't figure out the error or how to fix it.  Does anyone have an idea what is causing this and what the solution is?  I'm following the same method to install Selenium that I used previously for my Python version 3.10.2 and Selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl distribution package.  The "pip install.." syntax worked for that but now it's no longer working and I can't figure out why.
Python Error

Why not just pip install selenium ? Works for me on Python 3.12.2 and successfully installs Selenium 4.19.0

The test bed that I have Python installed on does not have internet access.  I have to import software into the environment.  Thus I can't run pip install selenium since it cannot reach the internet.  I have to download the distribution package and manually import it over into the server that has Python installed.  But that's the issue, when I try and execute it, the installation fails.

Why would you install selenium on a machine that doesn't have internet access?
